# Why did Toretto accept working for Cipher in first place?

Tags: plot-explanation, fast-and-furious-franchise, the-fate-of-the-furious

Something from Fast & Furious 8 was not clear to me: Cipher used Elena and Toretto's son more like reinforcement to her blackmailing rather than to get him for the job.

So, why exactly did Toretto accept working for her in first place?

I suppose it was something she showed him on the phone when they first met in Cuba, but I do not know that could possibly be.

Comment: Its like the basically very beginning of the movie, its the foundation that movie stands on. 
She threatened to kill Elena and Dom's kid that they had while ago. Dom didn't know she had a baby from him. Cipher threatened to  harm them. So Dom didn't have much of a choice rather than follow on to whatever she say him to do.

sorry for the short comment. but answer to your question IS the story we see in the movie

Answer (score 5):

> So, why exactly did Toretto accept working for her in first place?

Because she'd kidnapped Elena, an ex-lover of Dom's.

Cipher says...

> I think I need to **remind** you why you chose to be here.

This is when **we** find out about Elena being kidnapped...and that she has had a son that Dom knew nothing about. It's clear from the conversation between Dom & Elena that she had been kidnapped before telling Dom about his son.

You can't be *reminded* of something you don't know.

## **So, in Cuba, Cipher showed Dom a picture of Elena<sup>1</sup> being held**.

<sup>1 - The picture might have included the child but Dom didn't know the child existed and it would have meant nothing to him...although I'm sure he could have guessed.</sup>

Comment: But that's just speculation, right?

Comment: No...he's being reminded of why he chose..so he must have already known to be reminded...therefore it must have been Elena on the phone.

Comment: The better question is: Why couldn't Dom just let his teammates know what was going on?

Answer (score 0):

Since Cipher had Elena and Toretto's son, they could get Toretto to do anything. That includes getting him for the job.

Comment: But as far as I could understand he discovered she had his son while on her plane

Comment: I assumed the video Cipher showed him was of his captive son and wife.

Comment: I searched a bit about it in some of these "spoilery sites" and none of them confirmed. The most probable scenario is that being Cipher a cyber-terrorist she, somehow, she managed to discover Elena's secret and kidnapped her to use as blackmail. Don really went after Elena and Marcus was kind of Cipher's ace (or a fortuitous discovery for her) in case Toretto decided to give up.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto So basically both answers are correct. Cipher held Elena...right?

Comment: Yeah, I was just emphasizing that he knew about Elena (and even that is speculation). Marcus just came came along (that's sounds so horrible...)